# (iphone) how much memory UIImage takes up?

Tags: iphone, memory, uiimage

I'm having trouble with UIImage memory size.

1. When you have 320*320 resolution image data(png), when you load the image onto memory,
   using [UIImage imageWithData:], the resulting UIImage will take up 320*320*4?
2. does a screen size(resolution) affect the memory usage of an image?
3. Would the code below take up twice memory size of myImage or just single image memory size? (320*320*4) * 2 vs (320*320*4)? or something else?

   ```
   UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:];    
   myImage = [myImage scaleToSize:];
   ```

   when scaleToSize is defined as

   ```
   - (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size
   {
     // Create a bitmap graphics context                                                                                              


     // This will also set it as the current context                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

     // Draw the scaled image in the current context                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

     // Create a new image from current context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

     // Pop the current context from the stack                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     // Return our new scaled image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     return scaledImage;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

**TO CHECK MEMORY ALLOCATION**

If you want to test for specific images, run your application in the iPhone/Simulator while using Instruments.

[image: Run with the Allocations profile]

Make sure you choose the appropriate target. When you run the program, you'll see the memory space taken by a specific allocation.

---

**WHILE RUNNING**

You'll see the objects allocated in the window. Like this one, to which I attached iTunes.

[image: While running]

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the larger the image the more memory you will use, same goes for the amount of images you load into memory at once.